# Prefix mysql select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, prefix

How do I add a prefix to my select statement?

Currently I have this:

```
 return $this->hasMany(Score::class)
            ->select('id', 'port_id', 'criteria', DB::raw('AVG(score) as score'), DB::raw('count(score) as votes'))
            ->groupBy('port_id', 'criteria');
```

The selected `criteria` should have a prefix with `score_`.

How can I do this?

Currently result is:

```
1 1298 wifi 34 12
1 1298 animal_friendly 34 23
1 1298 adult_friendly 34 25
```

it should be:

```
1 1298 score_wifi 34 12
1 1298 score_animal_friendly 34 23
1 1298 score_adult_friendly 34 25
```

Comment: It's a query that get's criteria's with score's. The `criteria` columns should be prefixed with `score_`. So for example `score_wifi`.

Comment: It would help if you show an example of the data in your table, and your desired result.

Comment: Sure added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate data to values. Use the left side for a prefix.

```
concat('score_', criteria)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d69e87/1

Looks like in Larval it'd be written as:

```
DB::raw("concat('score_', criteria) as criteria")
```